# Splitting web page contention into section/column

Tags: css

I'm writing a sample page that uses external CSS sheet and I'm trying to split the content on the page into 3 different section (left, center, right) so that basically one section is on the left side, one is in the middle and one is on the right side.  I tried using columns as so:

```
.column {

        /* setting the number of columns to 3 */
        -webkit-column-count: 3; 
        -moz-column-count: 3; 
        -o-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
        /* setting the space between columns to 30px */
        -webkit-column-gap: 52px;
        -moz-column-gap: 30px; 
        -o-column-gap: 30px; 
        column-gap: 30px;

}
```

but this just splits the content into 3 different columns and text from one section/column overlaps into another section/column where its not supposed to be.

Is there a way I can do this so that I can create formatting for each  without affecting the others?

Comment: Can you post your HTML along with your CSS so we can see the exact effects of your current code?  Post it in a jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: There is the link.  Problem is I need to keep link one left, article in the middle, and the other links on the right side.  But as you can see article overlaps to the right side where only links should be.

Comment: If you want to controls which content goes into which column you should used grids technique. There is [a great tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/) on CSS Tricks I would personally recommend.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that and let you know how it goes.